# No performanceCounters/Requests Data in azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, iis, web-applications, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a web app running on prem (IIS) and I am trying to collect performance counters from it, although I have everything setup on my local and I am seeing all other types of telemetry in my Azure resource (requests, exceptions, traces) performance Counters are just not there,
it is worth mentioning that I am running 2 more web applications (they all work together) under the same site and same applicationPool in IIS and they are collecting Performance counters just fine, they all use the same package that contains our Application Insights implementation. Something strange I have noticed is that, when I am serving the application from Visual Studio, all the telemetry goes through, even performance counters, but, when I try with an installed Instance of my webapplications (using our inhouse installer ) any request or perfCounter for this particular web application just won't work.

I don't know what else to check, all 3 web applications should be collecting performance counters the same way since they are pretty much alike, and running under the same AppPool, same goes for requests.

this is what my appInsights.config looks like:

```xml
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
      <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="Processor Total - % Processor Time"/>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="W3SVC - % Processor Time"/>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="Win32 - % Processor Time"/>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_CLR_PROC??)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="CLR - % Processor Time"/>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(_Total)\Private Bytes" ReportAs="Process Total - Private Bytes"/>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Private Bytes" ReportAs="W3SVC - Private Bytes"/>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Private Bytes" ReportAs="Win32 - Private Bytes"/>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_CLR_PROC??)\Private Bytes" ReportAs="CLR - Private Bytes"/>
      </Counters>
      <!--
      Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:
      
      <Counters>
      <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
      ...
      </Counters>
      
      PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName
      
      NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
      
      The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
      ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
      ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
      ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
      -->
    </Add>
```

few more details: AppInsights sdk 2.4
.NetFramework 4.6.1

Thanks, all help is welcome

Comment: You can take a look at: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/performance-counters-for-monitoring-iis/ba-p/683389

Comment: thank you, @TheobaldDu I know the performance counters are being collected, when I serve my app from visual studio they do go to my Azure portal telemetry resource, for some reason this only happens on an installed instance of the app.